# Build multi-tool pipeline

Tags: maven, jenkins, jira, artifactory, bitbucket-server

I need to build a pipeline where we are using Jenkins, JIRA, Bit-bucket, maven, Artifactory. whenever a code is modified in Bit-bucket, a ticket has to be created in JIRA and build has to be triggered in Jenkins automatically. If the build is success, ticket has to be closed automatically else to be left open. After successful build the artifacts has to be pushed Jfrog Artifactory. The project is a maven project. Please guide me how to proceed step-by-step.

TIA